# How to fix bone size compared to mesh size

Tags: mesh, armature

[image]

The bones on my character got shrunk somehow and I'm not quite sure how. I used MBLab to generate the character but as you can see in the picture the skeleton is still connected to the mesh but is not super tiny? Any tutorials or advice that I can follow to learn how to fix this? Thanks.

I'm using blender 2.9.

Comment: From the units grid, it looks like the armature is actually normal size, and the mesh is huge. Check the scale on the mesh objects.

Comment: The scales are off like you suggested. However, if I adjust the scale of the mesh it adjust the scale of the armature with it. How do I adjust the scale of one but not the other?

Comment: Nevermind I don't know what I clicked before but now I can adjust the scales separately. Thank you for your help!